# ASP.NET MVC FileContentResult customise download dialogue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using FileContentResult to return a byte array of a system generated PDF to the user to either view or download. This works perfectly.

```
public FileContentResult ViewReport()
{
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myFileName);

    return File(myByteArray, "application/pdf");
}
```

What I'd like to know is - is it possible to hide the source in the download dialogue?

i.e. Hide or remove the "from" line in the dialogue,

http://i1216.photobucket.com/albums/dd364/nolana22/Download_Dialogue.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This dialog is browser specific and you have no control from a web site. The only thing that's *customizable* is the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header which you allows you to either download the file or open it inline.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure that is something the browser handles, unless you wanted to muck around with the headers being sent back and forth to eliminate your URL.

Comment: I'd looked into removing it using a header, but couldn't find any way of doing it. Was hoping there was something I'd overlooked on the MVC side. Thanks anyway!